# Specified cast is not valid. SQL Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datareader, oledbcommand

I keep getting back specified cast is not valid on the  `int result = myDataReader.GetInt32(0);` line when running the query using the parameter.
The thing is if I replace @Reg with text 'WM07 OGR' it works fine. However the string reg returns this so why the error?

```
string reg = RadComboBox1.SelectedValue;

//prepare sql statements
Command = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT MAX(Fuel.NO_ODOMETER_LAST) AS PrevMiles 
        FROM (Fuel INNER JOIN Vehicle ON Fuel.TX_VIN = Vehicle.TX_VIN)
        WHERE (Vehicle.TX_VEHNUMBER = '@Reg')", conn);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reg", OleDbType.WChar);
Command.Parameters["@Reg"].Value = reg;

myDataReader = Command.ExecuteReader();

if (myDataReader.Read())
{
    int result = myDataReader.GetInt32(0);
    Prev_Mileage.Text = result.ToString();
}

//cleanup objects
myDataReader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Comment as not 100% sure, but are the `''` required around the `@Reg` parameter in the command string?

Comment: What type has `NO_ODOMETER_LAST` in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The thing is if I replace @Reg with text 'WM07 OGR' it works fine.
>   However the string reg returns this so why the error?

It seems that you get the error if the query returns null because there is no matching `TX_VEHNUMBER`, then the cast to `int` fails.

So you have to check if it's null:

```
int result = 0; // insert default
if(!myDataReader.IsDbNull(0))
    result = myDataReader.GetInt32(0)
```

Apart from that it doesn't work because your parameter is interpreted as value, you have wrapped it in apostrophes here:

```
WHERE (Vehicle.TX_VEHNUMBER = '@Reg')
```

You just have to do this:

```
WHERE (Vehicle.TX_VEHNUMBER = @Reg)
```

Comment: !Thanks.. Arrrgg  the damn apostrophes got me.. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this.

```
Command = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT MAX(Fuel.NO_ODOMETER_LAST) AS PrevMiles 
            FROM (Fuel INNER JOIN Vehicle ON Fuel.TX_VIN = Vehicle.TX_VIN)
            WHERE (Vehicle.TX_VEHNUMBER = @Reg)", conn);
```

Or

```
Command = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT MAX(Fuel.NO_ODOMETER_LAST) AS PrevMiles 
            FROM (Fuel INNER JOIN Vehicle ON Fuel.TX_VIN = Vehicle.TX_VIN)
            WHERE (Vehicle.TX_VEHNUMBER = '?')", conn);
```

Or

```
Command = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT MAX(Fuel.NO_ODOMETER_LAST) AS PrevMiles 
            FROM (Fuel INNER JOIN Vehicle ON Fuel.TX_VIN = Vehicle.TX_VIN)
            WHERE (Vehicle.TX_VEHNUMBER = ?)", conn);
```

For more reference see following links.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/PassparametertoOleDbCommand.htm

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/01/24/ado-net-oledbcommand-parameterized-query-sequence-rule.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since it's getting into the below block...

```
if (myDataReader.Read())
        {
            int result = myDataReader.GetInt32(0);
            Prev_Mileage.Text = result.ToString();
        }
```

...I assume you have a record.  I'd check the **DataType** of `NO_ODOMETER_LAST`, as it might be a `varchar` or something other than an `int`.  If thats a case, you might need to use a `TryParse`.